# Is there a django plugin for a nice image list admin?

Tags: django, django-admin

I was asked to improve the list admin for the medialibrary of a django website (built with FeinCMS) where images are very important. There should be only images in the list admin, and they should be many, and dense. Furthermore it should still be possible to mark images for bulk operations. So, I'm seeking for roughly what the Wordpress Media Library offers (sorry, collegues).

I'm sure that this problem is quiet common. However, I cannot find a plugin offering all the functionality I need, including the template, the static files and a place for settings. Is there such a plugin?

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/20tab/twentytab-customadmin 
Should be what you are looking for, you can set icons for every section, and lot of other customizations.

Comment: Since you asked, i just wrote the documentation, you can find it at http://twentytab-customadmin.readthedocs.org/ , we also made lots of bug fixes and enhancements since version 0.6 , for every suggestion or critic please let me know or open an issue on github !